# Spring boot properties file override from command line

Tags: java, properties, gradle, spring-boot

I am having problem with Spring Boot and fat jar invocation from command line.I am trying to overide property from command line but without success.
I have parameter in the code:

```
@Value("${param1}")
private String param1;
```

and also I have put application.properties file inside src\main\resources with following content;

> param1=Param 1 value from properties file

When I build jar and run with:

> java -jar java-apns-notifier-0.1.0.jar --param1=Aaaaaaaaa

param1 is printed with value from application.properties file and not takes into account value from command line.
Project source code is [here](https://github.com/gandra/java-apns-notifier)

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to pass the arguments in your Application class.
You just need to change

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
```

to

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Santos!

Comment: I was getting lost until I found this answer !!! Many thanks @paulo-santos